# Переход на нужный компонент через ссылку на ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5, reactjs, express

Как реализовать переход на другой компонент путем ссылки такого формата: "/website.me/{nickname}". Переход будет осуществляться на один и тот же компонент, в url меняется только {nickname}. Через React router я использовал заранее написанный путь, но а как такой реализовать?

Comment: Это будут ссылки в React Router вида /:nickname, где nickname уникальный ключ в данных. Для вызова: this.context.router.push('/yournick')

Comment: А правильно работать таким образом? <Link to={`/${api.Account.username}`}>Account</Link>

Comment: если в переменной будет лежать нужный идентификатор, то можно. Но это по сути обычный статический роут получается